# How to find a file based on an array that contains objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out how to find a file that corresponds to specific qualities in one of it's arrays in mongoDB.

The file looks like this:

```
{
    full_name: {type: String},
    short_name: {type: String},
    business: {
        kind: {type: String},
        size: {type: String},
        fields: {type: String}
    },
    workforce: [{
        team_id: {type: String},
        department: {type: String},
        workers: [{
            id: {type: String},
            email: {type:String},
            title: {type:String}
        }]
    }],
    main_contact: {
        mail: {type: String},
        phone: {type: String},
        web_address: {type: String},
        mail_address: {type: String},
        fax: {type: String}
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to find is a file that has a specific `short_name`, in it's `workforce` array has an object that has a specific`team_id` **AND** in it's `workers` array, the file has an object that have a specific `email`. It's important to mention that the file in the `workforce` array must have all qualities mentioned above.

I tried few queries, none worked for me yet.
One of which:

```
        {
            short_name: "xyz",
            workforce: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    team_id: "000"
                    workers: {
                        $elemMatch: {
                            email: "a@a.com"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

What is the right query for this kind of search? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use $elemMatch to query in this way:

```
db.collection.find({
  "short_name": "123",
  "workforce": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "team_id": "111"
    }
  },
  "workforce.workers": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "email": "222"
    }
  }
})
```

But in my opinion, below one looks more simple and work the same:

```
db.collection.find({
  "short_name": "123",
  "workforce.team_id": "111",
  "workforce.workers.email": "222"
})
```

PS: I used below testing data set:

```
[
  {
    "full_name": "123",
    "short_name": "123",
    "business": {
      "kind": "A",
      "size": "S",
      "fields": "D"
    },
    "workforce": [
      {
        "team_id": "111",
        "department": "111",
        "workers": [
          {
            "id": "111",
            "email": "111",
            "title": "111"
          },
          {
            "id": "222",
            "email": "222",
            "title": "222"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "main_contact": {
      "mail": "A A A A",
      "phone": "123123123",
      "web_address": "www.a.com",
      "mail_address": "a@a.com",
      "fax": "321321321"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Query operator `$and` can be used to perform a logical AND operation on an array of one or more expressions.

It's syntax goes something like this:

```
{ $and: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> } , ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

So to find the right documents, the query can be written as:

```
{ $and: [ { short_name: "xyz"} , { workforce: { $elemMatch: {team_id: "000"}}}, {workforce.workers: { $elemMatch: { email: "a@a.com"}}} ]
```

Here, each expression is written inside the array and the `$and` operator gets applied on each expression

Read the docs for more details:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and